# Sigmoid Function in Java rounds up positive values to 1

Tags: java, machine-learning, neural-network, sigmoid

I'm building a neural network from scratch in JAVA to classify the Handwritten Digits Dataset from the UCI Machine Learning Repository. If you don't know about the dataset, each row of the data set has 64 integer features ranging from 1-16 with the last item of the row being the actual digit (0-9).

The model has one hidden layer with 300 neurons and an output layer with 10 neurons which outputs a binary mapping for each digit.

I have two 2D arrays that hold the weights between the hidden and input layers, (300 arrays with 64 values each), and the weights between the hidden and output layers (10 arrays with 300 values). I initialize these randomly at the beginning of the computation.

I use an array to hold a mapping of the desired output, so the mapping will look like {0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0} if the desired digit is 2, just like the output from the output layer neurons. I then compare both mappings and increment a success counter. Else, I train the network and adjust weights. I use the sigmoid function as the activation function in the hidden layer and the step function in the output layer.

My problem is that when the summation of each neuron in the hidden layer gets passed to the sigmoid function, it rounds up the values to 1. Thus, all the neurons from my hidden layer have an output of 1. Because of this, my backpropagation logic doesn't work properly because the error in some of the hidden layer neurons is calculated as 0 so the weights are not adjusted.

Here is the summation method

```
public static double summation(double[] input, double[] weights) {
    double sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        sum += input[i] * weights[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Here is the code for the sigmoid function and the step function

```
 public static double sigmoidFunction(double sum) {
    double result;
    result = 1 / (1 + Math.exp(-sum));
    return result;
}
public static double threshold(double sum) {
    double res = 0;
    if (sum > 0) {
        res = 1;
    }
    return res;
}
```

Here is the code that computes the output from the hidden layer neurons and the output layer neurons

```
//loop through the hidden layer weights
                //calculate the summation of the inputs to get the hidden layer outputs
                int i = 0;
                for (double[] weights : hiddenLayerWeights) {
                    //calculate the summation of each neuron
                    double summation = summation(inputs, weights);
                    //populate the hidden layer outputs array
                    hiddenLayerOutputs[i] = sigmoidFunction(summation);
                    i++;
                }
//calculate the output layer outputs
                int a = 0;
                for (double weights[] : outputLayerWeights) {
                    //calculate the summation between the hidden layer neurons and the output layer neurons
                    double summation = summation(hiddenLayerOutputs, weights);
                    //apply the step function
                    double neuronOutput = threshold(summation);
                    //populate the outputlayer output
                    outputLayerOutputs[a] = neuronOutput;
                    a++;
                }
```

Here is the code that trains the network

```
                        //calculate the error in each outputlayer neuron
                    //loop through the output layer outputs
                    for (int b = 0; b < outputLayerOutputs.length; b++) {
                        //compare each value with the desired outputs mapping to find the error
                        if (outputLayerOutputs[b] != desiredOutput[b]) {
                            //calculate the error for each output layer neuron
                            double outputLayerNeuronError = desiredOutput[b] - outputLayerOutputs[b];
                            //calculate the error for each hidden layer neuron
                            for (int k = 0; k < hiddenLayerOutputs.length; k++) {
                                //hidden layer neuron error is always 0 since output layer outputs is binary
                                double hiddenLayerNeuronError = outputLayerOutputs[b] * (1 - outputLayerOutputs[b]) * outputLayerWeights[b][k] * outputLayerNeuronError;
                                //adjust the output layer weights
                                adjustWeights(hiddenLayerOutputs, outputLayerWeights[b], learningRate, outputLayerNeuronError);
                                //adjust the hidden layer weights
                                adjustWeights(inputs, hiddenLayerWeights[k], learningRate, hiddenLayerNeuronError);
                            }

                        }
                    }
```

here is the adjustWeights method

```
public static void adjustWeights(double[] input, double[] weights, double learning_rate, double error) {
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        if (i < weights.length) {
            weights[i] = weights[i] + learning_rate * error * input[i];
        }
    }

}
```

When I run the model for 400 epochs, I get an accuracy of 9.2 which is very poor.
I would be most grateful if someone helps me find out how to resolve this. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Pretty sure you need to add a `.0` before your divisions. (e.g. here `result = 1 / (1 + Math.exp(-sum));`). If you do `1 / n` it will do an Integer division which will result in an Integer instead of a double. So change those to `1.0 / n`

Comment: I think as a good rule of thumb when doing such math is to always either write `1D` or `1.0` for the numbers. This guarantees that no integer operation is taking place

Comment: I tried this and I get the same result